# Как удалить зацикливание при создании HTML5-video, чтобы использование рабочей памяти не увеличивалось?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, видео, javascript-events

Мне нужно, чтобы между воспроизведением несколько идущих друг за другом видео не было прерываний и поэтому я с помощью свойства `preload = 'auto'` во время воспроизведения первого видео подгружаю уже следующее видео и затем сменяю одно на другое посредством функции `Node.replaceChild()`.

Но трудность заключается в том, что где-то происходит зацикливание и если открыть в Windows <kbd>диспетчер задач</kbd> на вкладке <kbd>производительность</kbd>, то мы увидим, что использование рабочей памяти постоянно увеличивается и видео при воспроизведении тормозят (не каждое и не всегда). Всего этого не должно быть и не наблюдается в **самом последнем** примере (внизу вопроса).

```js
//функция используется в EventListener "loadedmetadata", в createVideoElement()
function createNextVideo()
{
    if(++activeVideo == 2)
        activeVideo = 0;

    this.nextVideoElement = createVideoElement();
    this.nextVideoElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
    this.nextVideoElement.pause();
}

//функция используется в EventListener "ended", в createVideoElement()
function startNextVideo()
{
    var oldVideo = videoContainer.firstChild;
    
    this.nextVideoElement.play();
    videoContainer.replaceChild(this.nextVideoElement, oldVideo);
    
    oldVideo.removeEventListener('loadedmetadata', createNextVideo);
    oldVideo.removeEventListener('ended', startNextVideo);
}

//функция используется в createNextVideo()
function createVideoElement()
{
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.preload = 'auto'; //но без autoplay, т.к. оно отменяет preload

    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', createNextVideo);
    video.addEventListener('ended', startNextVideo);

    return video
}

var videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer'),
    activeVideo = 0,
    vidSources =
    [
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
    ];

var vidElement = createVideoElement(vidSources[0]);
vidElement.autoplay = true;
vidElement.src = vidSources[0];
videoContainer.appendChild(vidElement);
```

```css
video{background-color: red}
```

```html
<div id="videoContainer"></div>
```

**Как этот код выглядел до попытки решить эту задачу:**

```js
function createVideoElement()
{
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.preload = 'auto';

    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e)
    {
        if(++activeVideo == 2)
            activeVideo = 0;

        this.nextVideoElement = createVideoElement();
        this.nextVideoElement.src = vidSources[activeVideo];
        this.nextVideoElement.pause();
    });

    video.addEventListener('ended', function(e)
    {
        this.nextVideoElement.play();
        videoContainer.replaceChild(this.nextVideoElement, videoContainer.firstChild);
    });

    return video
}

var videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer'),
    activeVideo = 0,
    vidSources =
    [
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
    ];

var vidElement = createVideoElement(vidSources[0]);
vidElement.autoplay = true;
vidElement.src = vidSources[0];
videoContainer.appendChild(vidElement);
```

```css
video{background-color: red}
```

```html
<div id="videoContainer"></div>
```

Как мне кажется, в самом первом примере видео тормозит немного меньше, но не намного. Я надеюсь, что этот код более прост для понимания, нежели предыдущий.

**Тот самый последний пример:**

Чтобы развеять ваши сомнения (если у кого-то такие есть) о том, что с этими видео что-то не так, в нижеследующем примере вы можете убедиться, что с этими видео всё в порядке:

```js
var video = document.querySelector('video'),
    activeVideo = 0;
    videoSources =
    [
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
    ];

video.addEventListener('ended', function(e)
{
    if(++activeVideo == videoSources.length)
        activeVideo = 0;

    video.src = videoSources[activeVideo];
    video.play();
});
```

```css
video { background-color: red }
```

```html
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" autoplay></video>
```

В этом примере, как вы видите, возникают прерывания между воспроизведением видео и именно поэтому мне пришлось придумать вышеследующее решение, у которого теперь другие трудности / ошибки.

Итак, мне нужно решить такие задачи:

1. Как удалить зацикливание так, чтобы освобождалась память, а не увеличивалась как сейчас?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы видео при воспроизведении не тормозили? Возможно даже, что с удалением зацикливания это исчезнет.

Если есть вопросы, то, пожалуйста, спрашивайте!

*Пожалуйста, помогите решить эти задачи!*

Comment: в списке только два видео будет или неизвестное количество?

Comment: @Grundy, неизвестное количество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем всё решил сам. Нужно просто было удалить постоянное создание новых видео объектов, и оставить только два: проигрываемый и следующий (подгружаемый). Также использование события `onloadedmetadata` было неправильным, т.к. при его использовании мы получаем беЗконечный цикл подгрузки.

Вместо него взял событие `onplaying`. Теперь всё работает без затормаживания и память тоже не перегружается.

```js
var videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer'),
    nextActiveVideo = 0,
    nextVideo,
    videoObjects =
    [
        document.createElement('video'),
        document.createElement('video')
    ],
    vidSources =
    [
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
    ];

videoObjects[0].inx = 0; //установить index
videoObjects[1].inx = 1;

initVideoElement(videoObjects[0]);
initVideoElement(videoObjects[1]);

videoObjects[0].autoplay = true;
videoObjects[0].src = vidSources[0];
videoContainer.appendChild(videoObjects[0]);

videoObjects[1].style.display = 'none';
videoContainer.appendChild(videoObjects[1]);

function initVideoElement(video)
{
    video.preload = 'auto'; //но без autoplay, т.к. оно отменяет preload

    //loadedmetadata неправильно, т.к. при его использовании мы получаем беЗконечный цикл
    video.onplaying = function(e)
    {
        if(++nextActiveVideo == 2)
            nextActiveVideo = 0;

        //заменяем video elements друг на друга:
        if(this.inx == 0)
            nextVideo = videoObjects[1];
        else
            nextVideo = videoObjects[0];

        nextVideo.src = vidSources[nextActiveVideo];
        nextVideo.pause();
    };

    video.onended = function(e)
    {
        this.style.display = 'none';
        nextVideo.style.display = 'block';
        nextVideo.play();
    };
}
```

```css
video{background-color: red}
```

```html
<div id="videoContainer"></div>
```

Comment: осталось только обобщить этот код на то, что количество адресов в списке как ты указывал в комментарии - неизвестно :) ну и стоит быть аккуратным при добавлении свойств во встроенные объекты, в некоторых браузерах это может не сработать.

Comment: @Grundy, к чему это ты написал мне не понятно! Количество адресов можно использовать любое. Замени `if(++nextActiveVideo == 2)` на `if(++nextActiveVideo == vidSources.length)` и добавляй сколько хочешь адресов. Это я сократил, чтобы был минимальный код. Лучше бы проголосовал за ответ и за вопрос! ;-)

Comment: К тому. что ответ имеет недостатки и может работать не везде. _Замени if(++nextActiveVideo == 2) на if(++nextActiveVideo == vidSources.length)_ - стоит проделать это непосредственно в ответе

Comment: @Grundy, выписка из твоего отзыва: _при добавлении свойств во встроенные объекты, в некоторых браузерах это может не сработать._ Назови, пожалуйста, хотя бы один! ;-)

Comment: `IE` например :-) все зависит от версии браузера

Comment: @Grundy, напиши, пожалуйста, версию браузера. Например, я точно знаю, что даже в 6-ой версии такое работало. Ты что-то перепутал, видимо!